# Draw a triangle in assembly with fasm

Tags: assembly, fasm

I'm trying to draw a triangle in assembly using fasm but I just can't make it.
I have the following code to draw a rectangle and I thought that I should just decrease the [comp] value inside the cycle "ciclopinta" but that just doesn't work (or I'm doing it wrong).

```
org 100h
mov ah,4fh
mov al,02h
mov bx,13h
int 10h
mov [alt],50
mov [comp], 100
mov dx, 100
mov cx,100
ciclopinta:
ciclo1:
mov ah,0ch
mov al,23h
mov bh, 0
int 10h
dec cx
dec byte[comp]
jnz ciclo1
mov cx, 100
mov [comp],100
dec dx
dec byte [alt]
jnz ciclopinta

mov ah, 07h
int 21h
mov ah,4ch
int 21h

comp rb 1
alt rb 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> mov ah,4fh
> mov al,02h
> mov bx,13h
> int 10h
> ```

Why are you using a VESA function to set a legacy video mode? Normally that shouldn't work. Better use the following:

```
mov ax, 0013h  ;320x200 256-colors
int 10h
```

---

Near the end of the program you use the BIOS function 07h to ScrollWindowUp but you don't setup all the parameters for it to work. Best remove these lines `mov ah, 07h` `int 21h`

---

Your idea to decrement the *comp* variable is good. I suggest you write:

```
dec dx
mov [comp], dl  ;It's a byte-sized variable
```